# Firehose - Only copy specific specific data from stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm currently using a Amazon Kinesis Firehose to dump analytics data into a Redshift database table.  This table has grown very large over time, and queries are becoming slower and slower.

To speed things up, I would like to set up multiple Firehoses, and differentiate COPY command based on the content of the json document.

For example, if I have two json documents that look like the following:

```
  tableName: 'abc',
  data: 'some string of data'
}

{
  tableName: 'xyz',
  data: 'some string of data'
}
```

I would set up two Firehoses.  Firehose abc would run the COPY command in to table `abc`, and Firehose xyz would run the COPY command in to table `xyz`.  However, they should ignore each other's data based on the `tableName` specified in the json.  For example, if `xyz` is copying over data, and the json has `tableName: 'abc'`, it should ignore that document.

My question is, is this possible or does anyone have experience solving the problem of a Redshift table growing to massive amounts of data and slowing down queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [delivery stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-create.html) which allows you to introduce a Lambda function to perform transformations/filtering on the data before it goes to its destination.

[Here is an article that discuss how to set this up.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-kinesis-firehose-data-transformation-with-aws-lambda/)  It uses S3 as the destination but you should be able to use this same method with Redshift as the destination.